# Issue trying to use Firebase with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to set up a simple project on `Firebase` using `React`.
For that I follow this tutorial:
[Getting Started with React and Firebase - 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwNATxfUsgI)

After I run:

```
npm install firebase --save
```

I can see (as I expect) in the package.json dependencies this line:

```
"firebase": "^9.1.3",
```

Nevertheless, when I want to compile my code, looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ".....",
  authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myapp",
  storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "12456...",
  appId: "1:1.....:web:c......."
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/me/Documents/.../myapp/src'
```

My intention was to follow the tutorial, but it went wrong.
Is it that the document is out dated? Or is it that I missed some important detail?

I hope someone can point the issue and the way to solve it.

**Further added information:**

When I run this command in the project directory:

```
find node_modules -name firebase*
```

I get a rather long result containing lines like:

```
node_modules/firebase/....
```

and lines like:

```
node_modules/@firebase/....
```

Then trying:

```
find node_modules -name firebase.js
```

as well as:

```
find . -name firebase.js
```

Both commands return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the firebase module in the node_modules? Double-check it. Install it if don't.

Here is how I configured the Firebase v9. I created the firebase.js in the app root folder. Then I put the firebase configuration there and initialized the app in that file.

**firebase.js**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();
const storage = getStorage();

export { app, db, storage };
```

The values for the environment variables are stored in the .env file in the root folder of the app. The .env file must be added to the .gitignore because it contains sensitive data - credentials. I use the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme) to load the variables from the .env file into the process.env of the server.

Then I import things in my code like this

```
import { db, storage } from '../../firebase';
```

Comment: I added some information to my post, please have a look.
I think it should answer your first question. I also tried to imitate your code to see how it works. But I get exactly the same error message.

Comment: @Michel Double-check the path to the firebase.js from the file where you import it.

Comment: Thank you. In order to follow up with your suggestion, I tried to run some find commands but failed. Please have a look at the end of my post for details. I have to say sorry, because the information I intended to add when writing my previous comment was not properly inserted. This time I added what was meant to answer your first comment and also your second one (2 last find commands).

Comment: @Michel firebase.js is a file I have to hold the firebase configuration and initialization code. You can't find it if you haven't created it before. I edited my answer to make this fact more prominent.

Comment: The way you do things (certainly good) does not match the way it is done in the tutorial (mentioned at the beginning of my post) I am following. There is no firebase.js file in the tuto. So I need to sort out things in order to see what is going on.

Comment: @Michel the tutorial video was made in 2016. There was no firebase `v9` version back then. I think firebase had a lot of changes since then.

Comment: Yes, after all it is a bit of an outdated tutorial. You're right. I should find something more recent.

Comment: I want to set up a small project using React and Firebase Realtime database.

Comment: I am making some tests using your tips. How do I need to change your firebase.js to work with Realtime database insead of Firestore?

Comment: @Michel the config is similar, look here  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start Don't forget to export things from the firebase.js file.

Comment: Using your tips and doing a lot of reading and searching (& trying) I kind of got started, though there are still a number of unclear points. I am now on a somewhat more advanced issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750487/reusing-react-components-to-handle-a-different-db-collection).