# Reusing React components to handle a different DB collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a beginner question about React. I just wrote this component:

```
class MovieInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    };
  }

  ....
}
```

It is working fine, saving data in Firebase under a collection called movies.
I am starting to work on a second component looking like this:

```
class BookInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
    this.state = {
      books: []
    };
  }

  ....
}
```

I can already see that most of the code for the two components is going to be the same, making it pointless to write it twice. So here comes the question. How can I write a standard component, using props that I could pass, and have something like:

```
<MediaInput type='movies'/>
<MediaInput type='books'/>
```

instead of:

```
<MovieInput />
<BookInput />
```

The new component would probably look like:

```
class MediaInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
    this.state = {
          // Make use of some prop to set collection adequately ....
          // This is what I don't know how to do ....
          collection: []
    };
  }

  ....
}
```

It may be useful to set the background of my question, to say that I got inspired by [this tutorial](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/firebase-as-simple-database-to-react-app) to get started on writing the code above.

**........**
**After some more work:**

I am trying to implement a more generic component (*MediaInput*) (as suggested in the answer by *srgbnd*). I do that by modifying the code in *MovieInput* (already working). I still hit a few issues on its implementation:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    //if (prevState !== this.state) { // This line may need to be modified to the following.
    if (prevState.db !== this.state.db) { 
      this.writeUserData();
    }
  }

  writeUserData = () => {
    firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(this.state);
  };


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    .....
    // These 3 lines should be modified. Probably replacing movies by something like state.db.{props.type} ???
    const { movies } = this.state;
    movies.push({ ... });
    this.setState({ movies });
    .....
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with firebase database.

But if I assume that

```
Firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(this.state);
```

Handle on his own the differents keys of your state (like all the CRUD behaviour on each values) this simple trick should work with your `type` props :

```
class MediaInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
    this.state = {
          // The array will have the key 'movies' or 'books'
          [props.type]: []
    };
  }

  ....
}
```

But take care to always have a 'type' prop defined !

Comment: You may be right. The way the tutorial I use is written, the name of the variable (movies) happens to be the same as the name of the collection in the DB. That makes it kind of confusing to see how I can customize the code the way I need. Unless I change the variable everywhere. (This what I did to write the first component.) But it is unclear what I need to change to make it work the way I want now. This is why I put the link to the tutorial so that people can see where I am coming from.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would put the firebase details into a separate class to respect the [SOLID Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20design%2C%20the,of%20loosely%20coupling%20software%20modules.&text=The%20principle%20states%3A,abstractions%20(e.g.%2C%20interfaces).). For example:

```
class AppDatabase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  addCollection(data) {
    return firebase.database().ref('/').set(data);
  }
}
```

Second, I would use the type prop as you do.

```
<MediaInput type='movies'/>
<MediaInput type='books'/>
```

Finally, use the AppDatabase in the components. For example

```
import { AppDatabase } from '../services';

class MediaInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.appDatabase = new AppDatabase();
  
    this.state = {
      db: {
        [props.type]: []
      }
    };
  }

  addCollection() {
    this.appDatabase.addCollection(this.state.db);
  }
}
```

Comment: I must say I quite like the way you suggest to handle the problem. Therefore I am trying to use it. But it is not yet all clear to me. Mainly the last part; first, I don't clearly see how to you use the addCollection() function inside the MediaInput class, then (since I am not familiar with React syntax) I have a few more questions about how to transcript my working code (in MovieInput) to the more generic version (in MediaInput). I have added these questions to the end of my post, rather than in the comment. Please take a look if you have the time.